# Disable scrollbar when animating

Tags: css, animation, scrollbar, margin

I have a simple animation (via CSS) which brings my content from the bottom of the screen to the top. Margins are set to auto. My problem is that when this animation is coming up,on the right side it appears a scrollbar which persist till the end of the animation. I want to disable this scrollbar till the end of animation because my elements moves to the right for a few pixels after scrollbar disappers (because my margins are set to auto – and i want them to be so). 
Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set `body{overflow:hidden;}` before the animation and remove it after the animation ends.